# Encryption in Samsung Galaxy S8

Tags: security, encryption

Could someone explain what does it mean that Galaxy S8 with Android 7.0 is encrypted by default even when the phone has no password.

I thought it is encrypted because of PIN. And you should type correct PIN to decrypt data.

But I was told that even if phone has no password it is encrypted by default.

By encryption I mean that my phone has protected / unreadable data and I need to somehow decrypt it - by typing the password (pin, pattern, etc).

What does it mean it is encrypted by default ? Right now anybody could take my phone, boot it because it has no password and get access to all my data (photos, movies, sms, etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your device is encrypted (out of the box) and doesn't have a password, it means that - It is encrypted using the OEM encryption algorithm and the hardware characteristics **specific to your device** (see [Trusted Execution Environment](https://source.android.com/security/trusty/) ). However, because there is no PIN / pattern lock , one can boot into your device and access data

When you create a PIN/ pattern to permit access to your device, this PIN is used to [salt](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)) the encryption password and effectively change it. Hence PIN / pattern not only changes your encryption password but also prevents unauthorised access to your device. Everytime you change PIN/ pattern the encryption password is changed